# Scrapy, No Errors, Spider closes after crawling

Tags: scrapy

```html
for restaurant in response.xpath('//div[@class="listing"]'):
  
  
  
  
  restaurantItem = RestaurantItem()
  
  restaurantItem['name'] = response.css(".title::text").extract()
  
  
  yield restaurantItem
  
  next_page = response.css(".next > a::attr('href')")
  if next_page:
    url = response.urlJoin(next_page[0].extract())
    yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
```

I fixed all the errors, that it was giving me. Now, I am getting no errors. Spider just closes, after crawling the start_url. the for loop never gets executed.

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't find the `next_page` inside the DOM?

Comment: It never reaches that point, I tried writing a print statement just after for, it never enters the for loop...and, it is giving me no errors...

Comment: ok so it never finds the `div` you are trying to reach. Give a link maybe or some html code sample

Comment: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g255060-Sydney_New_South_Wales.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to find an element this way:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="listing"]')
```

You are telling I want to find a div that literally only has "listing" as its class:

```
<div class="listing"></div>
```

But this doesn't exist anywhere in the DOM, what's happening is the following:

```
<div class="listing someOtherClass"></div>
```

To select the above element you have to tell that the element contains a certain attribute text but can contain more. Here, like this:

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"listing")]')
```

Comment: an alternative is to use CSS selectors for this kind of class tests, i.e. `response.css('div.listing')`